# How do I assign a network IP & enable ssh during installation?

Tags: installation, uefi, grub-efi

I need to have a bootable usb flash disk with ubuntu 12.04 x64 EFI integrated any ideas?

Is there a way to install ubuntu 12.04.2 x64 as text based installation?

Like the ubuntu server install? And assign it network ip / enable ssh during installation?

Comment: Questions about 10.04 are considered off topic as they reach EOL, 9 May (2 days ago).

Answer (score 0):

you may want the mini iso, it is useless without Internet Access as you need it to install anything
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD - advanced users only
or the alternate cd
http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent
http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-alternate-i386.iso.torrent
If you need to use 10.04 (EOL btw) you can disable uefi and use bios from your bois/uefi or what ever you call it now days
also be sure any secure boot feature is off